# Youtube API, PlaylistItems: list, maxResults - it works incorrectly

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have a specific playlist that contains 562 videos.

My goal is to get all the IDs of each video and put them on the List (Java).

I am using PlaylistItems: list and setMaxResults (50L) - the highest possible. Yes, in the end it returns me my 562 videos, but if I try to create a HashMap (no duplicates, each value is unique) based on the video id, it turns out that out of 562 videos, about 50 are duplicates.

I still cannot identify the pattern, if you do setMaxResults (49L) - then the number of takes will decrease by 1. If you do setMaxResults (48L) - then the number of takes will grow ...
There is no setting setMaxResults (), the default is 5 - out of 562 videos with unique IDs, only ~ 340 will return at all ...

We get all the videos of the playlist

```
    List<PlaylistItem> playlistItemList = new ArrayList();
    
    try {
        String pageToken = "";

        while (pageToken != null) {
            logger.info("pageToken: " + pageToken);
            YouTube.PlaylistItems.List youtubePlaylistItemsList = youtube.playlistItems().list("snippet");
            youtubePlaylistItemsList.setPlaylistId("UUlatNLsHQYQ00TCT3Nfse6w");
            youtubePlaylistItemsList.setMaxResults(50L);
            youtubePlaylistItemsList.setPageToken(pageToken);
            PlaylistItemListResponse playlistItemListResponse = youtubePlaylistItemsList.execute();

            playlistItemList.addAll(playlistItemListResponse.getItems());
            pageToken = playlistItemListResponse.getNextPageToken();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("Error: ", e);
    }
```

playlistItemList.size() = 562.

Now let's select the number of unique video IDs

```
HashMap<String, String> realVideoIds = new HashMap<String, String>();

    try {
        youtubeVideosList = youtube.videos().list("id,statistics,snippet");

        for (int i = 0; i < playlistItemList.size(); i++) {
            if (realVideoIds.containsKey(playlistItemList.get(i).getSnippet().getResourceId().getVideoId())) {
                logger.info("getContentDetails: " + playlistItemList.get(i).getSnippet().getResourceId().getVideoId());
            }
            realVideoIds.put(playlistItemList.get(i).getSnippet().getResourceId().getVideoId().trim(), playlistItemList.get(i).getSnippet().getTitle());
        }

        logger.info("realVideoIds size: " + realVideoIds.size());
```

realVideoIds.size() = 512.

Total 562 != 512. As I wrote above, the smaller the MaxResults value, the greater the difference.

Thank you for your attention, I will be glad for any help =)

Comment: I would check the [issue forum](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:186600%2B) I seem to remember an issue report on this years ago.  Knowing the YouTube api team its probably still not fixed.

Comment: "I have a specific playlist that contains 562 videos." https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=UUlatNLsHQYQ00TCT3Nfse6w only contains 342 videos. Are there some private videos in this playlist ? Try disconnect of your YouTube account to check if the playlist videos counter change.

Comment: @DalmTo, thx for answer. You were right. The problem does exist and has not yet been fixed. For such a giant as YouTube, a problem of this nature (there is work at most for 1-2 days) looks like a joke ...

The problem has been known since at least June this year. And now, after almost half a year, they still have not fixed it. I thought more highly of YouTube.